# Cannot connect to TFS after adding domain controller Windows Server 2008

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008

Just added a domain controller to my server that is running tfs as well. And I believe Ive really "mucked" tfs now. Before it was configured to run at . It looks like I need to reconfigure TFS, I am just unsure how.

I can still access Sharepoint Central Administration. However when I try to get at the ServiceStatus.asmx for TFS I get 'Service is unavailable' using http://chicago:8080/.

This is confusing because of the DC though, the name should be changed to chicago.myrealtybrrand.com

One of my coleagues who is our resident TFS guru claims that you cannot run TFS on the same machine with a domain controller installed.

Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

TFS cannot be installed on a Domain Controller

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/611fcb83-8072-4013-8ea2-001b09a0319b/